# 'distance(from:to:)' is deprecated: all index distances are now of type Int

Tags: string, swift4

While calculating `String.Index` by using method: `index(_:offsetBy:)` of class `String`, compiler giving warning of deprecated method.
Following is my code snippet:

```
let string = "Hello World!"
let stringIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
```

> **Deprecation message**
>
> distances are now of type Int'index(_:offsetBy:)' is deprecated: all index

Any ideas how to silence this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift has created typealias `String.IndexDistance` for Int. Considering `Swift` a type strict language, explicitly type casting Int value into `String.IndexDistance` removes compiler warning.

```
let string = "Hello World!"
let stringIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance(5))
```

For more information: [String.IndexDistance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/indexdistance)

Comment: String.IndexDistance is now deprecated